# tips on software architecture for a CMS

Tags: architecture, software-design

I want to know some tips of good approach to write a CMS application/software for a gaming website such as gameloft. This question is not related to coding etc but please give tips for software architecture?

Comment: Read a lot of books, write a lot of software that actually gets used. Read this guide on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nice tips. Thanks. Can you also think of some tips or pointers on understanding architecture of a gameloft type CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software architecture is (in my favorite definition) the sum of all important decisions made in a software project. Important means: If you make the wrong decision changing it will become expensive possibly so expensive that it kills your project.

So if you want to make such important decisions you need as much information as possible about the problem at hand. Otherwise you are bound to make really stupid decisions. "A CMS like gameloft" is no way enough information to do anything.

So while you dig through a serious book stack gather information about the following questions:

- Who are your users
- What systems will your system interact with
- What are your goals?
- What are you constraints? Time, Money, People, Technology stack
- What are the top [ilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)

That should give you dozens of things to think about that will influence your architecture. If you then end up with a specific question like: "I have to do 1Million transactions on a cluster of three Raspi and they make me code it in Mathematica, how can I pull that of?" you might have a viable question for one of the StackExchange communities.

Also I don't see how gameloft is a CMS, but that's just me.

Comment: Much appreciated. Any specifics?